# VB.net Marshalling Error

Tags: vb.net, dll, marshalling

I have to create an array of structure type in VB.net. but I am getting error while marshalling this error. I have to pass this array of structure type in to Dll function.

Code:
Structure declaration:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Public Structure dx_entry
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=10)> _
        Public dx As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=3)> _
        Public type As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public narray As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public ctier As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public poa As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public poa_rsvd As String
       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=81)> _
        Public filler As String
    End Structure
```

Code of initiallization and marshalling:

```
Dim stpDx(2) As dx_entry
stpDx(1).dx = "5939" & Space(6)
        stpDx(1).type = "BK" & Space(1)
        stpDx(1).narray = Space(1)
        stpDx(1).ctier = Space(1)
        stpDx(1).poa = "Y"
        stpDx(1).poa_rsvd = Space(1)
        stpDx(1).filler = Space(81)
        stpDx(2).dx = "1231" & Space(6)
        stpDx(2).type = "BF" & Space(1)
        stpDx(2).narray = Space(1)
        stpDx(2).ctier = Space(1)
        stpDx(2).poa = "Y"
        stpDx(2).poa_rsvd = Space(1)
        stpDx(2).filler = Space(81)
        Dim pDxBuf As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(stpDx))
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(stpDx, pDxBuf, False)
        ezg_Block.pDx = pDxBuf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Audit_Demo_2307.exe
```

Additional information: Type dx_entry[] can not be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in to this a little bit, and the first issue seems that you pass an array into the `Marshal.SizeOf` method (it is this call that throws the exception). Since all members of your structure have a fixed size, you know that all instances of that type will have the same size. So, you can instead ask `Marshal.SizeOf` to return the size for one such instance:

```
Dim structSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(dx_entry))
```

The next thing is that `Marshal.StructureToPtr` copies the data from a structure, not an array of structures. So you will need some other way of copying your structure array to the allocated memory. There is no method that will do this for you in one call, but what you can do is to copy each of the structure instances in your array into a byte array (using the [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) method), and then copying that byte array to the memory pointed to by the pointer.

This is easiest to do as a two step rocket. First, let's make a method that converts the array of structures to a byte array:

```
Private Shared Function GetByteArray(ByVal array As dx_entry()) As Byte()
    Dim structSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(dx_entry))
    Dim size As Integer = structSize * array.Length
    Dim dataBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(size - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        Dim pTemp As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(array(i), pTemp, True)
        Marshal.Copy(pTemp, dataBuffer, 0 + (i * structSize), structSize)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTemp)
    Next
    Return dataBuffer
End Function
```

Second, use the `GetByteArray` method and copy the returned byte array to the memory pointed to by the pointer:

```
Dim data As Byte() = GetByteArray(stpDx)
Dim pDxBuf As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length)
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pDxBuf, data.Length)
ezg_Block.pDx = pDxBuf
```

I hope that does what you are looking for...

As a side note; since you in your structure have specified the fixed size for each of the fields, you don't need to pad the values with spaces in your code; this is taken care of by the framework when marshalling your data.

**Update**

To read the data back, you basically need to do the same thing, but backwards:

```
Private Shared Function GetStructArray(ByVal dataBuffer() As Byte) As dx_entry()
    Dim structSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(dx_entry))
    If dataBuffer.Length Mod structSize <> 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Argument is of wrong length", "dataBuffer")
    End If
    Dim elementCount As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dataBuffer.Length / structSize)
    Dim size As Integer = structSize * elementCount
    Dim result() As dx_entry = New dx_entry(elementCount - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To elementCount - 1
        Dim pTemp As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize)
        Marshal.Copy(dataBuffer, 0 + (i * structSize), pTemp, structSize)
        result(i) = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(pTemp, GetType(dx_entry)), dx_entry)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTemp)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Called like that:

```
Dim structSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(dx_entry))        
Dim newdata() As Byte = New Byte(structSize * numberOfElements -1) {}
Marshal.Copy(ezg_Block.pDx, newdata, 0, newdata.Length)
Dim newstruct() As dx_entry = GetStructArray(data)
```

**Note**: To get all this to work properly, you will need to tweak the structure a bit: it seems you need to increase the SizeConst by 1. This is since the strings are null-terminated, so there need to be a position for the null byte as well:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Structure dx_entry
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=11)> _
    Public dx As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=4)> _
    Public type As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public narray As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public ctier As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public poa As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public poa_rsvd As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=82)> _
     Public filler As String
End Structure
```

Comment: Thanks alot Fredrik,
Please let me know, if I have to retreive the data after the Dll function call, how I have to go ahead to do this.

Actually there are some values in this structure those will get upadated after the function call.

Comment: I heartly appreciate your help Fredrik. this solution is working for me. I nedd you help,I have a Union which contains a variable of structure type in C language. I used the following method to marshal it in VB.net
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> Public Structure grpr_output_block1
<FieldOffset(0)> Public drg As drg_grpr_block1
End Structure
Using in code - to pass as pointer in function
Dim stpGob1 As grpr_output_block1
Dim pGob1Buf As IntPtr=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOfstpGob1)
Marshal.StructureToPtr(stpGob1, pGob1Buf, False)
Ezg_Block.pGob1=pGob1Buf
is it right marshall?